# two sections in html overlapping in different devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html website, in which I reduced the size of the slider, then added a section and using media query aligned it for mobile devices. in desktop view it's completely fine, but in some mobile devices, the sections are overlapping with banner section and creating misalignment:

```html
<section>

  <div style="height: 300px;" class="ulockd-home-slider">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="pogoSlider" id="js-main-slider">
          <div class="pogoSlider-slide" data-transition="zipReveal" data-duration="1500" style="background-image:url(images/home/h4.jpg); height: 300px;">
            <div class="lbox-caption">
              <div class="lbox-details">
                <h1 class="fz45">Couple Heart Wedding Planner</h1>
                <h3 class="fz40 ulockd-mrgn120 ff-raleway">Best Event Organizer.</h3>
                <button class="btn ulockd-btn-thm2">Get Quote <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span> </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default ulockd-btn-transparent">More Info <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="pogoSlider-slide" data-transition="blocksReveal" data-duration="1500" style="background-image:url(images/home/h5a.jpg); height: 300px;">
            <div class="lbox-caption">
              <div class="lbox-details">
                <h1 class="fz45">We Are Creative Agency.</h1>
                <h2 class="ff-raleway">Your Dream Comes Out True.</h2>
                <button class="btn btn-default ulockd-btn-thm2">More Info </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default ulockd-btn-transparent">Contact Us </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="pogoSlider-slide" data-transition="shrinkReveal" data-duration="2000" style="background-image:url(images/home/h4a.jpg); height: 300px;">
            <div class="lbox-caption">
              <div class="lbox-details">
                <h2 class="fz48">Best Wedding Planner</h2>
                <h1 class="ff-raleway">We Organize Your Any Event</h1>
                <button class="btn btn-default ulockd-btn-thm2">Get Quote </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .pogoSlider -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</section>







<section class="iconss" style="height:250px;background-color: #F5F5F5 ">

  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <div style="margin-top: -35px; margin-left: 5px;" class="row">



        <table>

          <tr>
            ........
```

is there any way to stop this, the two sections are colliding in some devices. thanks in advance

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example of your code.

Comment: Hard to say from the provided code, but you might want to take a look at the negative top margins you are using, as they seem to be an obvious first look explanation